# Multiple textviews are not shown in Linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

i try to develop a small Android app and i use fragments for tab feature. Here is my tab3's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/European_Central_Bank" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Türk Lirası: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dolar:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Japon Yeni:" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Java part:

```
public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {
    private String turkishLira;
    private String dollar;
    private String japaneseMoney;
    URL url;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myCreateView=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag3_layout, container, false);

        getCurrencyInfo();


        TextView textView1 = (TextView) myCreateView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) myCreateView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) myCreateView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView1.setText(turkishLira);
        textView2.setText(dollar);
        textView3.setText(japaneseMoney);


        return myCreateView;
    }

    getCurrencyInfo() {...}
}
```

The question is only the first textview is shown on the phone. If i swap the 1st and 2nd textview, this time 2nd textview which has a static content is shown.
What am i missing? I don't have any problem in getCurrencyInfo method, i printed it's results.
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Are you sure getCurrencyInfo return correct values? what about trying textView1.setText("This is a test"); and tell us the result?

Comment: ah, you are right i think. it prints now 2nd textview. however i printed the results in function. i will trace the error. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that turkishLira, dollar, or japaneseMoney might be null or empty.

Have you debugged getCurrencyInfo() method?

You should maybe try

```
textView1.setText("turkishLira");
textView2.setText("dollar");
textView3.setText("japaneseMoney");
```

This will let you check wether this is a layout issue or a getCurrencyInfo() issue.

Comment: i will accept after 5 mins. it doesn't allow me now. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your **XML** file like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/European_Central_Bank" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Türk Lirası: " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Dolar:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Japon Yeni:" />
```